# How to setup Git for 2 related projects/modules (backend & frontend)

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a frontend in Vue and a backend API in node.js with feathers.
In IDE (IntelliJ Idea) I load them as modules and each has it's own .idea folder and .gitignore file.

I read all the pros and cons and while I prefer to have them separately as modules in IDE, I only want 1 repository.
I read the docs on git, idea and related posts on stackoverflow, but I can't find a clear, step-by-step guide.

How can I setup the Git to have both projects in a single repository?
I'm using GitLab if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody else needs this, here is how I solve it in the end:

1. Created a "group" of repo in Git.
2. Added 2 repos, one for FE and one for BE
3. Setup Gits in Idea for both modules

Idea will manage both of them at the same time.

Not quite what I want it but it works.

Comment: Just sharing who lends up here :),  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/258467/grouping-multiple-git-repositories-that-are-part-of-the-same-overall-project